# Side Menu in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

currently I am trying to create some documentation using doxygen. I wish to use the side menu instead of the top menu, I think it looks better. The issue is that it does not create it.

From the [doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) I found that to use the side menu instead of the top one I must set:

```
DISABLE_INDEX = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES
```

Unfortunately, the moment that I do this the top menu does disappear but the tree menu on the side is also not there.

The layout defined by navindex on my XML is the following:

```
  <navindex>
    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="Manuals" intro="List of related manuals:"/>
    <tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="References" intro="List of related references:"/>
    <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title=""/> 
      <tab type="hierarchy" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classmembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="files" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="files" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="globals" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="examples" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>  
  </navindex>
```

Which I know does work because it worked as top menu. Also, I see no error during the document generation.

I was wondering if somebody could give me a hint regarding something that I might be missing to make the side tree work.

Thanks in advance!

BTW I am using doxygen 1.8.11

Comment: I don't have any problems. Does doxygen give messages about automatically disabling settings? Try with some basic settings, i.e. default Doxyfile (doxygen -g) and set here DISABLE_INDEX and GENERATE_TREEVIEW. The remarks regarding the layout and XML I don't get.

Comment: This post is quite old. I had to do other things and I just had time to check this again. It turns out that in the project that I was given the headerFile was provided and not generated automatically. Now it is doing what I wanted, I just had to add the following line: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="$relpath^jquery.js"></script>